# Pronouns to start a phrase

Tags: pronouns

Can I start a phrase like this:
"your green eyes are beautiful" or "His/her green eyes are beautiful"
Thanks for reply.

Comment: Yes you can. Is there some reason why you think you shouldn't? (I would probably phrase it as "Your eyes are a beautiful green", but that does have a subtly different meaning and your way is fine.)

Comment: Any reason why not?

Comment: a student mine introduce a phrase like this: is beautiful your eyes green. So, I correct it, but, fix the mistakes. I wrote on her test explaining what is the right way. Tks.

Comment: *My, your, his, her, its, our, their* are not pronouns, they're **determiners**. From Cambridge: "in grammar, a word that is used before a noun to show which particular example of the noun you are referring to".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is perfectly OK to start a sentence with a pronoun.  Indeed, **I** is one of the most common words to start a sentence. **Your** is not actually a pronoun: it is a determiner. The difference is that a pronoun **replaces** a noun:

> the book is on the table -> **it** is on the table

whereas a determiner goes before a noun to say which one you are talking about:

> the book is on the table  -> **my** book is on the table

Compare that with **mine** which is a relative pronoun, and you will see that the noun **book** disappears:

> the book is on the table  -> **mine** is on the table

Here is an [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_+I%2C_START_+you%2C_START_+he%2C_START_+the%2C+_START_+my%2C+_START_+your&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_START_%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20my%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20your%3B%2Cc0) showing that both pronouns and determiners are very common at the start of a sentence.

Comment: I don't see an NGram.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost: Oops. Link fixed.

Comment: @Jave, you wrote - *"a pronoun replaces a noun"*. But the examples you quoted show that a pronoun replaces a Noun Phrase. Actually that is true - a pronoun replaces a noun phrase. If and only if the noun phrase contains nothing except the head noun, in that case a pronoun can replace a noun.